# The field 'Form1.answer' is never used

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am getting a random word from a dictionary using:

```
var word = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\\CTEMP\\Dictionary2.txt");
```

and displaying it only partially for the player to guess using:

```
hintTextBox.Text = GetPartialWord(word[new Random().Next(word.Length)]);
var answer = word[new Random().Next(word.Length)]; // answer = word from dictionary
```

However I am not able to compare the word the user enters to the word from the dictionary.

I have tried :

```
  private string answer;  //assign answer to word from dictionary

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (answerTextBox.Text == answer)
{MessageBox.Show("You Guessed The Word !");
```

However I am getting the following warning:

> Warning   CS0169  The field 'Form1.answer' is never used  WindowsFormsApplication2

Any ideas on how I can compare the answer to what is entered in answerTextBox?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, error. However the output is still wrong as I am not comparing successfully.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
var answer = word[new Random().Next(word.Length)];
```

Here you create new variable instead of using class level one. In `if` statement you compare value of textbox with class level variable. Also, you get warning because you never assign value to class level variable but compare value of textbox.

That line should be changed to:

```
this.answer = word[new Random().Next(word.Length)]; //or without "this."
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight @Roma !

Comment: did you purposely delete your latest answer? I was just about to give it a try. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you accepted another correct one. I can undelete it is you want.

Comment: Oh, OK. I just happened to try that one first. If your method works too, I would have happily accepted it, as it shorter and looks relatively simpler.

Comment: Yes please, I would like if you undelete it. I will go for your method if it works as it is shorter, as I said before

Comment: @UnknownR, I restored my answer. Try if you want.

Comment: Thanks, i think I am missing something from my side. As the word is not changing. I will keep trying. Thanks again @Roma